# How can I add a hyperlink in a Azure bot message text

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have recently started creating a Azure Bot in Node js. I want to add a hyperlink in one of the bot response and send a proactive response after user has clicked on it.
Something like:

`Please click this link to complete the payment`.

and the link should be a hyperlink that will redirect to an endpoint.

I have tried finding a way to achieve it but so far, I haven't been able to achieve. I have seen the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Can some one suggest me the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use markdown syntax.

> The text must be treated as markdown formatting and rendered on the
> channel as appropriate.

Hyperlink markdown syntax :

```
[click this link](https://www.google.com/)
```

As per your code it would look like the following:

```
Please [click this link](www.greetings.com) to complete the payment
```

**Reference:**

1. [Format text in chatbot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/format-your-bot-messages)
2. [Markdown syntax](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)